# Mahout: How to Use Random Forests to Make Online Predictions

Tags: hadoop, mahout, random-forest

I just tried the BreimanExample on UCI's glass data after working through this simple example:

https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/breiman-example.html

My question is, once I create a RandomForest in Mahout, how do I "load it" in order to make predictions with it?

With sklearn in Python this is easy, just pickle the forest to disk and load it later, put it behind a web server for live interaction, easy.

But what about with Mahout and Hadoop?  If I build a RandomForest at scale, how do I capture and use the output to make future predictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to follow this example : https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/partial-implementation.html
BuildForest is for building the model and TestForest code will show you how to load the model to make predictions.

Comment: I tried running this example but got `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10` using number of trees parameter -t 10 on both mahout-0.9 and trunk versions. Anyone has same issue or solution?